# Virgin value of the Higgs field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, higgs, symmetry-breaking

https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-hierarchy-problem/naturalness/

According to Matt, the 246 GeV vev of the Higgs field came from:

> "We get these two quantities — the average value and the mass of the field and particle — by looking at how the energy of empty space depends on the Higgs field. And that energy, as in any quantum field theory like the Standard Model, is a sum of many different things:
>
> energy from the fluctuations of the Higgs field itself,
>   energy from the fluctuations of the top quark field,
>   energy from the fluctuations of the W field,
>   energy from the fluctuations of the Z field,
>   energy from the fluctuations of the bottom quark field,
>   energy from the fluctuations of the tau lepton field,
>   …
>
> and so on for all the fields of nature that interact directly with the Higgs field… I’ve indicated these — schematically! these are not the actual energies — as blue curves in Figure 5. Each plot indicates one contribution to the energy of empty space, and how it varies as the Higgs field’s average value changes from zero to the maximum value that I dare consider, which I’ve called vmax."

So what is the value of the virgin higgs field vacuum expectation value before it interacted with any of the matter fields?